# taller than any student or taller than any other student

Tags: phrases

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> a)
>   1. John is taller than any student in his class.
>   2. John is taller than any other student in his class.
>
> b)
>   1. No student is taller than John in his class.
>   2. No other student is taller than John in his class.

Comment: a(2) is correct as it's both more natural and avoids a logical paradox (as John is also a student in his class).
b(2) is slightly more natural but it would be better to say "No other student in his class is taller than John."

Comment: possible duplicate of [The occurrence of comparative degree](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150183/the-occurrence-of-comparative-degree)

Comment: The b sentences leave open the possibility that another student is taller than John outside, but shrinks when he enters the classroom. (Not likely, but confusing none the less).

Answer (score 4):

Is John a student? If so, the second sentences in both cases are correct. In the first ones John could just as well be the professor.

I would suggest another sentence if at all possible:

> John is the tallest student in his class.

Answer (score 0):

A2, B2 both make sense - Options 1 don't as John can't be taller than himself.
B2 sounds rather contrived.

Can you go for 'John is the tallest student in his class'?