# Is “irritance” not a word?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

I thought the word *irritance* was a word — but it isn’t one according to Google and my dictionary.

It sounds correct; what is the word I should use?

By *irritance* I mean something that’s being irritating, like a person kicking the back of your plane seat is an irritance.

---

After researching more, I’ve found the word I was looking for was ***nuisance***.

Comment: Depending on context, probably *irritation* or *irritant*.

Comment: Unless you say how you might use it, we cannot say what word you “should” use instead.

Comment: _Irritation_? Or _irritants_? Or _bus stop_? Or _sherbet lemon_? Or perhaps something entirely different. Very hard to tell you what word you should use if you don't tell us **what it's supposed to mean**.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about *bus stop*.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you're mixing up *irritation* and *annoyance*.

Comment: @Rupe No... I am pretty sure there is a word that ends in 'ance' with a meaning similar to what I think is irritance!

Comment: @downloader And *annoyance* is not such a word?

Comment: @Rupe Although that is a word that means what I want, no, it isn't :(

Comment: Same question here: http://www.ukhippy.com/stuff/showthread.php/36710-irritance-!-!

Comment: @Josh61 That's a big coincidence! I used almost the exact same example!

Comment: Wow I've used irritance before and never knew it's "not a word", whatever that means.

Comment: @NeilKirk  Words are things that people say and write — and preferably which other people understand. You can never determine that something is **not** a word merely by consulting a dictionary. If you don’t find it, you still don’t know whether it is a word. [See here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/150183) for a bit of expansion over what I’ve said below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although *irritancy* certainly exists as a noun, something that is irritating is normally referred to as an *irritant* or an *irritation* — or less commonly and usually with a human agent only, an *irritator*.

---

(lifted out of ephemeral comments)

I haven’t found any dictionaries that yet contain *irritance*, although there do exist [published books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22irritance%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) that happen to use it. This usually means that a word is too new or too rare to bother mentioning, since even catachrestic uses are documented by full dictionaries.

So although anyone would instantly understand what you meant by the word *irritance*, your computerized spellchecker might not like it and your readers might consider it a non-standard use.

It is important to remember that no dictionary purports to list all words, not even the OED. So just because a dictionary doesn’t list a word does not mean that that word is “not a word”. Absence of evidence never constitutes evidence of absence. There are many reasons why dictionaries leave words out.

You should therefore never conclude that the omission of a dictionary entry for a word somehow “means” that that word is not an “actual” word. As [the link to published works](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22irritance%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) shows, there actually are a few people who **do** — albeit on rather rare occasion — write *irritance* in published books. A few examples of actual printed use for *irritance* are:

> - But it is the interaction, perhaps even mutual **irritance**, set up between these two  worldviews and their increasing lack of it, that motivates many of the striking  cultural innovations of the twelfth century. 
>          ―[*The Medieval Greek Romance*, by Roderick Beaton, 2012](http://books.google.com/books?id=lT0n5UtGDoIC&pg=PA11&dq=%22irritance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iIXFU6f7DJSiyAS4iID4Cg&ved=0CGoQ6AEwEw#v=onepage&q=%22irritance%22&f=false)
> - ... from a German perspective about those people who in fact were deported.  Survivors of the Nazi regime are thereby labeled as a national **irritance** and Jews  of younger generations become part of the reminder to Germans of a history that they might rather forget. 
>          ―[“Journalismus als Beruf: Truth and the anti-Semitic journalist stereotype in the writings of Maxim Biller and Rafael Seligmann”, dissertation by Robert Anthony Feldman, 2008](http://books.google.com/books?id=HaZrI8-r0DsC&pg=PA94&dq=%22irritance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iIXFU6f7DJSiyAS4iID4Cg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22irritance%22&f=false)
> - Another feature of lung **irritance** is the longer term effect, which occurred  following exposures to the atmosphere produced by the pyrolysis of flexible  polyurethane foam at 600° C, and also by the non-flaming oxidative  decomposition of ... 
>          ―[*Advances in Combustion Toxicology* by Gordon E. Hartzell , 1988](http://books.google.com/books?id=z7rjY4YN1-wC&pg=PA61&dq=%22irritance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iIXFU6f7DJSiyAS4iID4Cg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAQ)
> - CTC International  undertakes human studies to assess cutaneous **irritance**, sensitisation potential and the efficacy an acceptability of a wide range of products. 
>          ―[*New Scientist*, advertisement, 1984](http://books.google.com/books?id=6idhDboGmZoC&pg=PA51&dq=%22irritance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iIXFU6f7DJSiyAS4iID4Cg&ved=0CFYQ6AEwDg#v=onepage&q=%22irritance%22&f=false)

My personal recommendation would be not to use *irritance* to mean an *irritant*, but there is no law forbidding you from doing so.

Comment: So `irritance` is not a word, but `irritancy` is? English is strange... :)

Comment: Ah but to balance things up we have *annoyance* with no *annoyancy*.

Comment: @downloader I didn’t say *irritance* was not a word, merely that we normally use those other words.  [See here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irritance%2Cirritancy%2Cirritant%2Cirritation%2Cirritator&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cirritance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cirritancy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cirritant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cirritation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cirritator%3B%2Cc0)  and [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22irritance%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en).

Comment: @tchrist But surely, `irritance` would be in the dictionary??

Comment: @downloader Well, I haven’t found any dictionaries that yet contain *irritance*, only published books that happen to use it. This usually means that it is too rare to bother mentioning, since even catachrestic uses are documented by full dictionaries.

Comment: @tchrist So, in general, it *is* possible for a word to exist without being in the dictionary? It's just about awareness of a word? Like 'Google' was a few years ago?

Comment: @downloader If people use a word, then it is a word.  I listen to *potatonic rappazodical hop-metal*.  There, those are words now; I've just made them.  Not that they refer to anything in particular, nor that anyone will use them after this point in time--but they are words nonetheless.

Comment: @downloader No dictionary purports to list all words, not even the OED. So just because a dictionary doesn’t list a word **does not mean** that that word is “not a word”. Absence of evidence never constitutes evidence of absence. There are many reasons why dictionaries leave words out. You should never conclude that the omission of a dictionary entry for a word somehow “means” that that word is not an “actual” word.  As the link shows, people do on rare occasion write *irritance* in published books, and you would certainly be understood. It’s simply rare and perhaps non-Standard.

Comment: Anyway, after Googling (a word! ;) a bit more, I've found the word I was looking for was `***nuisance***`

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted because your comments helped me a lot! I don't have enough rep to +1 :(

Comment: @Anonym- I really like *potatonic*  - A near vegetative state induced by extended periods of television viewing.

Comment: @downloader Thanks, I’ve promoted the comments into the main answer, and include a few citations.  I still wouldn’t use it myself.

Comment: @Jim Feel free to prove me wrong and make *potatonic*'s existence less ephemeral.  By the sounds of it, it actually could have a use.

Comment: @tchrist Now I *really* wish I could +1 you :) this is a very good, detailed answer! No wonder you have 51.7k rep!

Comment: @medica Thanks :). And with the upvotes I received on my question, I now have > 15 rep, so I'll +1 as well :)

Comment: @tchrist I have enough rep to +1 now :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you want [irritant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irritant) from the free dictionary:

> causing irritation, especially physical irritation.

Even if it is ongoing, it is an irritant or irritation:

> - How small *irritants* become big issues—and what to do about them.
> - The under-representation of the backcountry areas in colonial legislatures was an ongoing source of *irritation* in the colonial South.

Perhaps your supposition that *irritance* is a word stems from the way *irritants* is pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

> It sounds correct, what is the word I should use?

That depends upon what you want to say:

> An *[irritant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irritant)* is something which irritates.
>
> *[Irritation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irritation)* is the act or state of being irritated.

*Irritance* probably sounds correct to you because, having been derived from *irritant*, it follows a regular pattern: defiant, defiance; reliant, reliance; omniscient, omniscience; and so on.  Middle English even had *pleasant, pleasance*, though we've since replaced the second word with *pleasure*.  In theory, there is nothing wrong with coining *irritance*, but you must consider whether or not your audience would understand the word--or if you would do better to use one that already exists.